# How to run Processing sketch in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios5, processing

As part of a student thesis project, my group and I are making, among other things, an app that displays data visualization that will be done in Processing. We were wondering what's the best way to do this?

We were initially thinking of converting the Processing file (.pde) into a video and just playing it in the app but I've heard that converting it into a .dvg is better and I've also heard you can just run the .pde in Xcode.

Does anybody have advice on what's the best way to do this and how?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry for the question, but what do you want to do ? an Iphone App ? a Mac App ? may be you can easily make a web page using processingjs ?

Comment: I'm making an iPhone app with Xcode and objective C but just want to see if there is a way for the app to play a Processing sketch without turning it into a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a few ideas that could work, but I don't have an iPhone and have only tested in Simulator:

1. [iProcessing](http://www.luckybite.com/iprocessing/)
2. Davide from [SketchPatch](http://sketchpatch.net) showed me a springs demo on his phone running better than iProcessing using his [P5Nitro](https://github.com/davidedc/P5Nitro) library.
3. If you're .pde file is not using a lot of java specific libraries, you could try to port the project to [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/download/) for iOS. There's also a nifty [oF for Processing users](http://wiki.openframeworks.cc/index.php?title=OF_for_Processing_users) guide since the project is inspired by Processing. You'll be right at home with setup()/update()/draw() and touch events.

Goodluck !

Comment: Hi George, I tried running a couple of the examples from iProcessing in Xcode and the builds failed. Wonder if it's cos' they were for ios4 not ios5. But I'll look into the other ideas you suggested. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I'm still using the ios4 sdk so can't test right now. Is your project very complex ? From one point of view it might be simpler to use OpenFrameworks, since it's all good to go on iOS at native speed. I might sound daunting to use Objective C++, but OpenFrameworks abstracts a lot of the complexity, a bit like how Processing does with Java (since Processing is essentially a Java library).

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help. The project is not that complex, I think. We're basically activating normal video with DV layered over it when the iphone is in a specific geo-location. Unfortunately I'm the only person "courageous" enough to take a stab at programming without any background in it and our deadline is at the end of August so there's not a lot of time to learn new stuff. I'm now hearing that after effects might be good for visualizing data as well.

Comment: Playing a movie should be trivial in oF(there are samples as well to get you started). Another idea is to try html/js: you can get geo-location data from the browser and you can use the video tag to playback video (you need to watch for the supported format). Regarding data viz, if you're comfortable with After Effects and got the basics of programming (variables, loops, conditions, arrays, functions) maybe you could import the data you want to visualize into After Effects by writing a script (AE is scriptable with JavaScript)

Comment: no worries, feel free to vote/tick answers on your questions as you find it. welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

I made changes in package iprocessing.org, some functions such as capturing the microphone, accelerometer, geolocation, among other things were not working.

Also updated the version of Processing.js implemented in the code. I redid almost all the code and created this iOS APP: http://spincles.dekwilde.com.br/
The code is available at this link:
https://github.com/dekwilde/Spincles

Now I call him iProcessing 2.0